Union of an element of a set with the set containing the element
I recently stumbled upon the axiom of infinity which states that
$$\exists A:\emptyset \in A \land \forall x:(x\in A \Rightarrow x \cup\{x\}\in A)$$
Now I am confused regarding the union of $x$ and $\{x\}$. I always thought i can only take unions of sets, but isnt $x$ just a single element of A? Or do I just regard everything as set then?

Yes, in set theory everything is a set.

There is also a version of set theory with "atoms" (objects that are not-set): $\mathsf {ZFA}$. It was the original Zermelo's theory (1908). In that case, the "elementary" operations: pair, union, are defined for objects in general.

Sets can be elements of other sets. In a sense, you could say that a set theory involves a binary operator $\in$ and two kinds of objects: the elements, which are the ones that go on the left of $\in$, and the classes, which go on the right of $\in$. Sets are classes that are elements, atoms are elements that aren't classes, proper classes are classes that aren't elements. In standard ZFC there are only sets, in BGN there are proper classes and sets.

$x \cup {x}$ is the set whose members are: the members of $x$, and $x$ itself.

But do I then consider numbers as sets as well? So what would $2\cup{2}$ mean then. What does 2 contain?

The definition you consider does not imply there is any $2$ in the set $A$, so asking about $2\cup{2}$ seems unjustified.

The answer is actually that it depends. In “pure” set theory, everything is a set, and the natural numbers are typically represented by the finite von Neumann ordinals. Thus “0” is represented by $\emptyset$ (the empty set), “1” is $\{\emptyset\}$, “2” is $\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$, and more generally if $x$ is a von Neumann ordinal then the next largest ordinal is $x \cup \{x\}$
But you can also have set theory with both sets and non-sets; the non-sets are usually called “atoms” or “urelements”. The atoms usually (I think) include the natural numbers. In set theory with atoms, if $x=2$ (an atom), then I’m pretty sure $x \cup \{x\}$ is not a valid expression (because $x$ is not a set).
My impression is that set theorists usually work in pure set theories, whereas set theory as used in other areas of math (“normal” math like analysis, geometry, etc.) is more likely to be with atoms.

The definition does not imply there exists any $x$ in $A$ which is not a set.
It starts from $\emptyset \in A$, and that is the only explicit assumption about elements of $A$: the empty set is an element of $A$.
Then for $x=\emptyset\in A$ you have that also $x\cup\{x\} = \emptyset\cup\{\emptyset\} = \{\emptyset\} \in A.$
That in turn implies $\{\emptyset\}\cup\{\{\emptyset\}\} = \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}\in A$.
And so on.
Nowhere in this sequence of implications appears any $x$ not being a set.
